# Evaluating $\int \cot x \csc^2x \,\mathrm{d}x$ with $u=\cot x$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$

> Evaluate the integral using the indicated substituion. $$\int \cot x \csc^2x \,\d{x}, \qquad u= \cot x .$$

Differentiating both sides of $u$, then making the substitution: $$
\begin{align}
u &= 
\phantom{-}\cot x, \\
\d u &= -\cot x\csc x \,\d{x}, \\
\d x &= -\frac{\d u}{u \csc x}.
\end{align}$$
$$\int -\frac{u\csc^2 x \,\d{u}}{u\csc x} = \int -\csc x \,\d{u}. $$

Apparently, this was not an adequate approach, because $x$ is still part of the integrand. What should be done instead?

Comment: You have not completely turned the integrand to a function of $u$. Try do more.

Comment: $\csc^2(x) = 1 +\cot^2(x) = 1 + u^2$.

Comment: Also, $\mathrm d\cot(x) = -\csc^2(x) \mathrm dx$, not $-\cot(x) \csc (x)\mathrm dx$.

Comment: I had confused it with another formula, but I got it now. Thank you, @xbh.

Comment: **$\LaTeX$ Tip:** Try using \cot x, \csc x and \mathrm dx to get $\cot x$, $\csc x$ and $\mathrm dx$ respectively.

Comment: @MauricioMendes You are welcome. That one seems to be $\mathrm d \csc(x)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting different answers when integrating using different techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453558/getting-different-answers-when-integrating-using-different-techniques)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $du=-\csc^2x\,dx$, rather than your wrong differentiation. This implies the integral is
$$
\int\cot x\csc^2x\,dx=\int-u\,du=-\frac{1}{2}u^2+c=-\frac{1}{2}\cot^2x+c
$$
On the other hand, rewriting the integral as
$$
\int\frac{\cos x}{\sin^3x}\,dx=\int(\sin x)^{-3}d(\sin x)=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sin^2x}+c
$$
is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

**For alternative way:**

$$\int \cot x \csc^2 x dx$$
$$=\int \frac{\cos x dx}{\sin^3 x}$$

Now you can advance taking $\sin x = z$ .